# Suburb for LocalBusiness addresses

Tags: seo, schema.org, local-seo, address

I recently improved our local SEO when I realised the critical importance of the suburb, despite the central location of our church in Christchurch, New Zealand.

Updated From:

> 346 Manchester Street, Christchurch

Updated To:

> 346 Manchester Street, Christchurch Central, Christchurch

Now I'm trying to update Schema to ensure the `LocalBusiness` details are 100% optimised. The problem is, there's no place to quote the suburb.

Current Schema:

```json
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Church",
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"addressLocality": "Christchurch",
"addressRegion": "Canterbury",
"postalCode": "8013",
"addressCountry": "New Zealand",
"streetAddress": "346 Manchester Street"
```

Should I place the suburb in the `streetAddress`?

Should I change `addressLocality` to "Christchurch Central" and change the `addressRegion` to "Christchurch"? The provence here is "Canterbury".

All Schema examples on their website do not include the suburb. I've looked up their examples on Google Maps and found the suburb isn't quoted anyway. As I've discovered, however, the suburb IS quoted in local address searches using Google Maps in New Zealand. This is critical for local SEO here.

Comment: Maybe you can help properties such as containedInPlace or containsPlace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand something. But you are on the right way;)

The change

> 346 Manchester Street, Christchurch
>
> Updated To:
>
> 346 Manchester Street, Christchurch Central, Christchurch

is not the end point of your optimization. Correctly it should be `346 Manchester Street, Christchurch Central City, Christchurch, Neuseeland`. Why? Because of you everywhere should put your address 146% EXACTLY as it is written in the Google place id database.

Try to input `346 Manchester Street, Christchurch` into the [place id search tool by Google](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id): you get an autosuggest `346 Manchester Street, Christchurch Central City, Christchurch, Neuseeland`.

Indeed, your current naming, `346 Manchester Street, Christchurch Central, Christchurch` is much nearer to the optimal notation - thats why you realize `the critical importance of the suburb`. But, its rather the critical importance of correct place notation.

Be aware to always publish the correct place notation and you are done. In the structured data too, but there it is fully enough if you add `hasMap` with a link to the Google Maps, containing your place ID - https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Google&query_place_id=ChIJ833B7S6KMW0RbDLrM70xuow